# nodejs - use axios with tor as a proxy in cli script

Tags: node.js, terminal, axios, command-line-interface, tor

I have tor installed on my macOS 10.13.6
I want to use it for my axios xhr requests as a proxy but after a lot of searching I'm unable to find any useful resource. I've not configured tor as a proxy for my browsers and I'm not sure if is working after I run it from terminal. Is there any way to use it as I need and to check if works well?

I'm trying with this code but not sure if tor is really used

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const axios = require('axios');
const socks = require('socks-proxy-agent');
const httpsAgent = new socks(`socks5://127.0.0.1:9050`);

axios({
 method: 'GET',
 baseURL: 'https://foo.bar',
 url: 'baz/faz',
 httpsAgent: httpsAgent,
});
```

Comment: Firstly, make both an httpAgent _and_ an httpsAgent if you want to be secure going through Tor. Secondly, try to request an onion URL. If it succeeds, you're going through tor. If it fails with a DNS resolution error, then you're not hitting tor. You can also try to configure a browser you don't actively use (firefox is a good choice for this) to connect to your local Tor daemon as a proxy for testing. The Onion test is always the most surefire way to tell if it's working.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I've successfully configured tor with firefox and I'm able to open `.onion` websites. The problem is now with axios. I've tried to connect to DuckDuckGo onion version but I get this error `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion` in the `url` field of axios config I have put this address `http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/`

Comment: Right - you're using `http`, not `https` there. Therefore it's going to try to use the `httpAgent`. You need to supply one alongside your `httpsAgent` - just providing `httpsAgent` won't work.